# Debugging Genymotion in Eclipse on Windows 7

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device, genymotion

I've been using the Genymotion Android emulator for 2 weeks now. So far all was good, I was able to debug and everything was working fine (and in a pretty fast way too).

Suddenly the debugger went crazy yesterday: it jumps over certain lines of code, does not execute certain methods, shows that an `obj` instance is not null (on mouse over) but does not execute `if (obj != null)` code blocks which follow, etc. etc.

Is there any solution for this?

In fact, I think it's behaving the same way with the standard Android emulator too. And that also started yesterday. So I am just puzzled what I can do in order to fix this weird problem and continue working normally.

Needless to say I cleaned and rebuilt my project a few times in Eclipse. Rebooted my PC too. Nothing helps for now.

Comment: I found this question and the answers to it but they are not specific at all and thus no much help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739078/android-code-acts-crazy

Comment: I reinstalled Eclipse, replaced it with the latest (Luna). Reinstalled the Android SDK, just kept the old Genymotion installation. I was hoping this to help but no, still no luck at all. I still see in the debugger how lines of code are simply skipped for no reason. Starting a bounty now. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I even recreated my virtual device in Genymotion with the hope that this would clear some older/cached copies of my app and deploy the real code to the device. No luck with that too. Also, the debugger constantly shows (I think all) values of variables as "errors during evaluation".

Comment: How about on a real device (just to make sure the problem is definitely the debugger)?

Comment: @PaulRatazzi I haven't tried that yet.

Comment: Have you tried performing a clean build, and starting eclipse with the `-clean` argument?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes, I tried that too yesterday (found that tip somewhere on the web). And today ... I just downloaded and installed a brand new Eclipse. I was almost sure this would help but no. No luck.

Comment: @peter.petrov Almost always this means that the app you're actually running doesn't actually match the code in the IDE. Did you try deleting `bin` and `gen` contents, cleaning all projects, and uninstalling the app from the device?

Comment: @matiash Yes, I know that's what this usually means. I tried all those. They don't have the expected effect though. To me it seems, it's just loading some old code from somewhere, or some of the tools has some quite serious bug.

Comment: @peter.petrov I would suggest taking the apk from bin and using dex2jar + JD-GUI (or similar) to peek inside the compiled classed.dex and check whether the parts that are misbehaving are "current" or not. At least that should help determining whether the problem is liable to be with the tools or the emulator itself.

Comment: @matiash Thanks, tried that just now. Seems the correct (latest) code is in the apk. What do you think, what does that mean now? I am quite confused now.

Comment: @peter.petrov I would try installing that APK manually and then attaching to the process (just to see if there might be any problem with the upload to the emulator). And maybe try with a device as Paul suggested. But I'm sorry to say that right now I have no idea what could be the cause of this :(

Comment: @matiash OK... nevertheless thanks a lot. I will keep fighting with this issue in the coming days... and hopefully I will get some help here from SO too.

Comment: @peter.petrov good luck! at least the dex2jar test indicates that the apk itself doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: @matiash Issue fixed. It was a bug in my code which was causing this weird behavior (or my misinterpretation of what I was seeing). I am still puzzled, I still don't get how exactly my bug was causing this behavior. I will rethink it all tomorrow as it's too late now. Thanks for the help, the tips were really useful!

Comment: @peter.petrov happy to hear it. if you can post a reproducible example it would be swell! :)

Comment: @matiash Not sure if I will manage it. I still don't understand how that problem happened, and then how it got fixed after I fixed the bug in my own code (in a view which I have). This seems like a pretty buggy thing to me.

Comment: @peter.petrov Does this weird behavior happens when you debug and use the stepping function? you try to step in and something else happens, you try to step over and unless you have another breakpoint somewhere else the program just executes?

Comment: @TacB0sS Well, I think ... something like that, yes. As if it's executing an older version of my code.

Comment: @peter.petrov Do you have methods with generic types declaration in some of your objects? e.g. public <T extends Something> void method(T t){...}

Comment: @TacB0sS I don't have but I use built-it ones e.g. ArrayList<Point[]>. Actually I think that ... I think when I added that code the problem started appearing. Why do you ask? :)

Comment: @peter.petrov see my answer... let me know if this sounds familiar

Comment: @peter.petrov sounds like the code your IDE is showing is not the code your device is running. Try deleting your `build` folder or use the `./gradlew clean` command

Comment: The debuggers use the CLASS file to do the step execution, and the IDE positions your source code (.java) in the line being executed. But some JAVA structures are transformed / optimized (for example explicit or implicit final values, access to parent classes' private members from inner classes, ...) That's why you might see some inconsistencies stepping through your code.

Answer (score 3):

I can't be sure that this is the issue, but I have experienced a weird debugging behavior when I had an interface with two method with the same generic **type name** but different **signatures**, e.g.:

```
public <T extends Something1> void method1(T t){...}

public <T extends Something2> void method2(T t){...}
```

The issues I've encountered were:

- I could not evaluate any expression.
- Count not step in or over, only run... till the next breakpoint.
- I'm sure there were other things but I've looked over them as I was only trying to get things done :|

For some reason this is [known issue in Eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=344856) and has not been resolved for the last few years...

So the real solution for this is actually to rename one (or both) of the generic param names to so:

```
public <T1 extends Something1> void method1(T1 t){...}

public <T2 extends Something2> void method2(T2 t){...}
```

Surprisingly this solved the bug for me which drove me nuts for a real long time!

I hope this is the issue :)

Comment: I don't think this is exactly my problem as I don't have any generic methods. In fact I have just one view and one activity. Still +1 from me for trying to help and for pointing out some clue which makes some sense (even though it may not be really identical to my scenario/issue).

Answer (score 1):

this could be not related to the emulator then
as standard emulator is not working fine too.

this could be some miss-sync between the source code and the compilation result
so the debugger starts acting crazy

i had this one time, 
the sol was related to the option **add line number attributes to generated class files (used by the debugger)**

to find that option:
1- right click on the project you have trouble with

2- select properties

3- from left pane, select java Compiler

4- at lower part of right pane, under **Classfile Generation**:

*here you may have 2 cases:*

1- that option is NOT checked, so just check it, click apply, and a clean-build might be good

2- if that option is CHECKED, the uncheck it, click apply, close the dialog, clean the project, and buil.
**THEN** re-open the dialog and navigate to that option, CHECK it, click apply, then close dialog
clean project and build.

**Note**: it might be better while doing this to unselect `Build Automatically` option from `Window` menu
then re-enable it once you have done above steps.

good luck

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but I tried it and it doesn't help.